# Como detectar la diferencia entre formatos de fecha y su orden

Tags: php, laravel, regex

Hola como puedo detectar la diferencia entre formatos de fecha por ejemplo 21/12/2018  vs  2018/12/21 y en cualquiera de los casos formatearla a AÑO-MES-DIA  en php. 
Ya intente de esta forma

```
 $nueva_derivacion = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($RELEVAMIENTO->fechaderivacion));
```

Pero el problema es que el orden y formato varia en el mismo campo lo cual me genera un error y fechas con este formato 26/12/2018 pasan a ser 01-01-1970.

Por lo cual debo poder detectar el orden y formato para posteriormente pasarlo  a AÑO-MES-DIA

Comment: ¿De dónde sale dicha información? De un formulario, de una base de datos, de un servicio, ...

Comment: Siempre pueden ser uno de esos 2 formatos 21/12/2018 vs 2018/12/21???

Comment: Si tu estas haciendo el backend y el fontend deberias saber coo llegara ese dato y de la forma en como llegue deberias "normalizarlo" al formato inficado en la base de datos.

Comment: esta en una base de datos, necesito organizarlos de forma homogenea para luego trabajar con estadisticas y si las fechas estan asi me genera error

Comment: Tenés posibilidad de identificar previamente cuáles son las fechas que vienen en el formato DDMMYYYY o YYYYMMDD? O siempre te devuelven fechas en distintos formatos?

Comment: no hay forma, de hecho trato de toma mes año y dia por separado pero me las formatea al año 1970. en este caso creo se necesitara solucionar con expresiones regulares

Comment: Claro, entiendo pero siempre te devuelve distintos formatos de fecha la DB? Porque si de antemano sabes que el formato es YYYY/MM/DD, podés usar una función `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2018/12/21')`.

Comment: PORQUE EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO ME ESTA ESTE ERROR cuando intento imprimir con echo?
ErrorException (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string


$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-10-10');
    echo " DESPUES "; 
    echo    $datetime;     ;  @kleith

Comment: Si, porque es un objeto, la forma correcta es `$fecha=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2018/12/21');
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar mi problema de esta forma

```
$date1 = strtr($RELEVAMIENTO->fechaderivacion, '/', '-');
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes aceptar tu respuesta :)